# Resolve $y' - 2y = e^{3x}$ as a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am required to show that  $y=e^{3x} + 10e^{2x}$ is a solution to the DE $y' - 2y = e^{3x}$. My working is as follows, but I am not sure how to complete it.

$$
\begin{align*}
y' - 2y &= e^{3x}\\
y'(e^{-2x}) -2y(e^{-2x}) &= e^{3x}(e^{-2x}) \tag{apply IF}\\
(y')(e^{-2x}) + y(-2e^{-2x}) &= e^{x}\\\tag{integrate wrt x}
y(e^{-2x}) &= e^x + C\\
y &= e^{3x} + Ce^{2x}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: what you got there is general solution. To prove that a particular $y=f(x)$ satisfies a DE, just put $y=f(x)$ in DE and check if it is consistent.

Comment: Any boundary value?

Comment: Given $y=e^{3x} + 10e^{2x}\implies y' = 3e^{3x} + 20e^{2x} $. Subs in the de and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=e^{3x}+10e^{2x}\implies y'=3e^{3x}+20e^{2x}$

Then, $y'-2y=3e^{3x}+20e^{2x}-2(e^{3x}+10e^{2x})=e^{3x}$

Thus, it satisfies the given $DE$ and hence is a solution to given $DE$

Comment: I should have differentiated forward and not integrated backwards!

Comment: @bryansis2010: right!!